# xparse's 's' argument returns \Gamma and \Delta, instead of \BooleanFalse and \BooleanTrue

Tags: xparse, optional-arguments, starred-version

The `xparse` [documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) says,

[image]

But that's not what I get when I test `s`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{s}{#1}

\begin{document}
\myfunc    % should return \BooleanFalse; actually returns \Gamma
\myfunc*   % should return \BooleanTrue; actually returns \Delta
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Also, `\IfValueTF` doesn't return 0 when `*` is absent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfuncB}{s}{
    \IfValueTF{#1}{1}{0}
}

\begin{document}
\myfuncB    % should return 0; actually returns 1
\myfuncB*   % should return 1; actually returns 1
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\BooleanTrue` and `\BooleanFalse` cannot be typeset: they are boolean variables and don't make sense outside of a `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` test.  Try `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{True}{False}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik But is it a happy coincidence that Gamma is `\char"00` and Delta is `\char"01`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Fair enough, but see edit to OP for more.

Comment: @campa No, `expl3` booleans are `\char"0` and `\char"1`, and that's why OP gets that output.  Regardless it doesn't make much sense to use them for typesetting

Comment: Careful: `\IfBooleanTF`, not `\IfValueTF`. The latter tests for the special marker `-NoValue-`

Comment: @campa Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\BooleanFalse` and `\BooleanTrue` are boolean variables not meant for typesetting.  You can only use them in a `\IfBooleanTF` test:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfuncB}{s}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{1}{0}%
}

\begin{document}
\myfuncB    % returns 0
\myfuncB*   % returns 1
\end{document}
```

---

`\IfValueTF` can't be used either because it checks if the argument is `-NoValue-`, and neither `\BooleanTrue` nor `\BooleanFalse` are `-NoValue-`, so the test returns true always.  `\IfValueTF` is supposed to be used with optional arguments like `o` and `d`.

---

Under the hood, `\BooleanFalse` is `\char"0` and `\BooleanTrue` is `\char"1` so they take the zeroth and first character of the current font, whatever that happens to be.  In the OT1 encoding, `\char"0` and `\char"1` are the glyphs Γ and ∆:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{cmr10}
\end{document}
```

> [image]